# Announcing a third-party search engine for Math StackExchange.

Tags: discussion, search

Approach0 is a math-aware search engine. “Math-aware” means you can add math expression(s) as some of your keywords to have search engine help you find similar expressions. Check out here: https://approach0.xyz

To restrict matches to this site paste the string "AND site:math.stackexchange.com" into the search window (this removes AoPS matches - very useful when searching for duplicate targets)

This is my side-project, hopefully it can be useful in some cases to help Math SE users find more similar questions before posting a question for help.

I would love to hear any feedback from you guys.

EDIT: If you are unable to get expected results or have questions related to searching on Approach0, Please go to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46148) (otherwise there will be too many comments in this thread). For those who want to report a bug (not have to be confirmed) or request a feature to Approach0, please go to [project issue page](https://github.com/approach0/search-engine/issues). (You do not have to be familiar to GitHub to create an issue, just click that button and write some description on things you feel not running well). This will attract potential contributors from GitHub to participate and get developers' attention.

Comment: This does look useful. The greatest problem about searching for math is that someone may be discussing the expression you have in mind with different variable letters, which utterly stumps general search engines. As an experiment, I tried searching for `$st-s-t$`, and got many relevant results that discuss the two-value [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) with variables different from $s$ and $t$. Well done!

Comment: The second experiment didn't go as well -- trying to find [this answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534296/are-there-any-limit-questions-which-are-easier-to-solve-using-methods-other-than/1534312#1534312) I searched for `$\lim_{t\to\infty} {2t \over t+\sin(t)}$`, but got no results. Only when I replaced $\sin(t)$ with $\sin t$ did it find the original post. The original had `\frac` instead of `\over` and that equivalence worked fine, but it may be a useful improvement for it to know that brackets around arguments to simple functions such as $\sin$ and $\log$ are optional.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you for your advice. I have already noticed this problem, and indeed plan to improve on this. This is an early version, it simply thinks \sin(t) and \sin t as being structurally different. In future version, I plan to do "query expansion", e.g. query \sin(t) would become \sin(t) **or** \sin t. But this comes with some difficulties, such as the ambiguity of expending \sin 2\pi (computer needs to know math conventions to guess where is the bracket). Also, if there are too many expansion possibilities within an expression, that will consume a lot computer power/time too.

Comment: Looks good and seems to work very well so far! One suggestion: instead of having the raw link as the title of each result I think it would be better if the title was the acctual title of the question found. Sometimes seeing the title makes it easier to see if the match is what you are looking for. Anyway good job!

Comment: Thanks for your nice work. That was something we always need in MSE. I appreciate your work too much.

Comment: @Winther Good suggestion! Although that will consume more disk, and re-crawl entire MSE. I definitely think that will help users a lot. I plan to add "title" in search results in the next big version.

Comment: Wow, Wei Zhong -- really nice job with this, I'll be trying it out.

Comment: With some fine tuning, this may be a **huge** improvement of MSE. I hope that the MSE staff will join you soon in the development phase and later implement your search system together with the actual one. (+1) Good job.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well, how I wish. I would love to do things that I feel useful. However, not very optimistic (see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9125), people would rather use old tricks and choose to trust Google in any ways. Long way to go.

Comment: @WeiZhong: count me on your side when a discussion about that will arise.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you, appreciate that.

Comment: I find it quite confusing that the question title is not displayed with the results. Instead I get an out-of-context snippet.

Comment: Should this not be tagged with `feature-request`?

Comment: @Myridium Yes, someone above already suggested to add title in results. Please be tolerant on my first minimalism version, the next version I wish to add title into search results. If adding tittle can improve the readability of snippet, then of course it is the next priority in my project TODO list.

Comment: A search engine like this has the potential to be a revolutionary improvement for this site. It could enable you to type in any equation and instantly find everything that is written about it. It could make everybody work 1000 times faster. Well done. I don't see how google is ever going to compete with this (as others seem to think). And of course it's not going to be perfect right away. Improving and fine tuning is going to be a continuous process.

Comment: @Myridium, In a recent version, title has been added into search results. Please do a hard refresh on your browser to make sure these effects will be displayed.

Comment: @Winther, See my comment above.

Comment: @WeiZhong - If you wish to follow up each comment and suggestion with a comment of your own (nothing wrong with that), then I think a chat room may be more suitable.

Comment: Why is the site disabled on mobile?

Comment: @Myridium Sure. If you have any feedback regarding to this topic and my recent changes, we can go to chat room next time.

Comment: @asmeurer Firstly, the user-friendly math expression editor that Approach0 is using (i.e. mathquill) does not support mobile phone. Secondly, I think typing math expression on mobile can be very frustrating and inefficient (many symbol input needed). In the future, if we can find some open-source tools that handles hand-writing math input really well, at that time I think we can enable mobile site.

Comment: @WeiZhong it's more frustrating to not even see what the site looks like. Why does it supposedly work on a tablet but not phones? There's no such thing as a site that works on a tablet and not a phone. Why not just let the site work and if it ends up being difficult to use, then users can figure that out for themselves.

Comment: @asmeurer I appreciate your feedback, but *mathquill* does not work on mobile, it works on tablet though. If you show users the mobile site and users find they cannot even input a query, would they figure out themselves that this site does not support mobile phone? My guess is they will give up and say: this entire search engine does not work at all. Do not get me wrong, this is a problem I also want to improve, but not until we have a hand-writing math recognition input that can fundamentally offer user good mobile experience.

Comment: How do I search a word which must have two keyword?, thank you.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki No, all examples having more than 2 keywords are used to demonstrate that Approach0 supports **combined search** of both math and usual term keywords. One keyword will also work. Read the "user guide" and if you still find problem to search certain query, ping me here and I will definitely try to offer help.

Comment: How useful is more your search engine than google's, pros and con?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki When you have math expression(s) in query, a math-aware search engine will help you a lot (in terms of math symbol $\alpha$-equivalence and commutative rule awareness). But for non-math query, Google is not an easy one to compete with as you may guess. Also see  Martin Sleziak's comment below about the difference according to his experience.

Comment: Could this tool be used to search groups of duplicates on the site? For example to identify most frequently repeated questions so that they can be linked/grouped/merged/whatever ?

Comment: @Sil Some queries (such as [this one](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7De%5E%7B-n%7D%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Cfrac%7Bn%5Ek%7D%7Bk!%7D%24%2C%20value&p=1) ) are indeed helpful to find many repeated/related questions. However, currently the "search engine" does not run any algorithm to identify duplicate posts offline nor do any actively data mining. But from technical point of view, there is no obvious obstacle neither. The only problem is, I am focusing on my work/research, I also want help from other developers for maintaining this non-commercial side-project.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I correctly interpret @JackD'Aurizio's comments as saying that Approach0 should be incorporated directly into this website. This seems to me a bit too optimistic. (Now that Jack's a mod he has somewhat better chance to do something about that.) But at least mentioning Approach0 in help center would probably help to get more people to notice it and it would give Approach0 a kind of "semi-official" status of site's search engine. I have made a feature request here: [Should we add external searches in some help pages about search?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27421)

Comment: Dear @WeiZhong, is there an analogue of approach0 but for MathOverflow?

Comment: @Watson There was a [request](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3082/is-there-any-third-party-search-engine-for-mathoverflow/3085#3085) actually. Mathoverflow is more "professional" mathematical Q&A site, I have a concern that if most people using Approach0 are not familiar with those advanced math knowledge, introducing it into search results can be a little distracting. And those Mathoverflow users are likely to know where to find answers already? I may be wrong. But if you have your reasons, welcome to go to that thread and express your interests, or, explain why it may be helpful?

Comment: @WeiZhong Hello, thank you very much for this amazing tool. Do you think it would be possible to add parameters for the score or number of views?

Comment: @HereToRelax Thank you. What do you mean by adding parameters for number of views?

Comment: @WeiZhong, like say someone just wants to search through popular questions or answers, not all of them. (This can be useful for finding big duplicates).

Comment: @HereToRelax Aha, I see. So StackExchange has that number shown in each thread right? I can definitely index them so you can see those numbers in approach0 search results, as well as the number of votes for a particular question (but they may be stale and outdated when shown, and I may not have resource to update those numbers frequently, does this sound good to you?). But I am afraid to be able to query those will need further technique improvements.

Comment: @HereToRelax For follow up comments, I invite you to chat in this chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46148/in-the-search-of-a-question, I will response there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seemed to me as a good idea to make a CW answer where Math.SE users could add the problems they stumbled upon while using this search engine. (EDIT: And we can also use [this chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/46148/in-the-search-of-a-question-using-approach0-or-by-other-means?tab=general) for discussing Approach0-related issues and searching for questions in general.)

- I was unable to enter things like `$\Bbb N$` $\Bbb N$, `$\mathbb R$` $\mathbb R$, `$\mathcal S$` $\mathcal S$, `$\mathfrak c$` $\mathfrak c$ or `$\mathscr F$` $\mathscr F$. When I tried to enter them, it ended like `mathbb R$` instead. (EDIT: As explained, in [a comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/announcing-a-third-party-search-engine-for-math-stackexchange/25003#comment97971_25003), this depends on capabilities of mathquill, which is used as math input editor. However, it is still possible to edit directly raw query. Examples: [searching for $\mathbb R$ cardinality](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cmathbb%20R%24%2C%20cardinality&p=1), [searching for $\mathbb R$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cmathbb%20R%24&p=1), [searching for $\mathfrak c$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cmathfrak%20c%24%2C%20%242%5E%7B%5Caleph_0%7D%24&p=1), [searching for $\mathfrak c$ and $\aleph_1$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cmathfrak%20c%24%2C%20%24%5Caleph_1%24&p=1).)
- I tried out of curiosity to search `F\dashv G` $F\dashv G$, and it seems that the `$\dashv$` $\dashv$ symbol is assimilated with `$\cap$` $\cap$, as the two searches give the same result. The same happened with `$\times$` $\times$ and `$\vdash$` $\vdash$. Looking for expressions with different variables is excellent, but different symbols can completely change the meaning of an expression.
- [Searching `$\vee$` $\vee$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cvee%24&p=1) returns a large number of irrelevant results, with many terms unrelated to $\vee$ being highlighted. i.e. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550646/differential-geometry-proving-an-expression-for-the-principal-curvature) is the 5th result, in which the symbol $\vee$ does not appear at all.
- I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934367/sum-of-the-series-sum-1-infty-fracn2n) asking for the sum of $\frac n{2^n}$, which we have seen many times before.  Typing $sum 2/2^n into the search box did not find any of them. I know I have answered one.
- I searched for `\oint` $\oint$, but I only got results related to `\int` $\int$. [I tried for](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Coint%20%5Cfrac%7Bdz%7D%7B1-z%5E2%7D%24&p=1) `\oint \frac{dz}{1-z^2}` $\oint \frac{dz}{1-z^2}$ which is an integral that appears quite often but it did not yield any correct results.

Comment: Approach0 is using _mathquill_ as math input editor, currently it does not support these commands you mentioned (e.g. mathbb), however, you can still search it. But instead of inputting it in query box, you should use "raw query" box, or just paste your `$\mathcal S$` into query box. You will need to do this until newer version of _mathquill_ supports these commands.

Comment: Yes, this is because dashv is defined as "CAPCUP" category in Approach0 source code (see https://github.com/approach0/search-engine/blob/master/tex-parser/lexer.template.l#L772), this can be inaccurate due to my limited math knowledge. If anyone feel there is a better category it should be put into, just send a pull request to the source code :)

Comment: The previous comment is related to the problem pointed out by @ArnaudD. So perhaps it is reasonable to ping him.

Comment: @WeiZhong I think that searches with $\aleph_1$ are good example of situation where searching for *arbitrary* variables instead of the ones given in the query does not work well. AFAIK the letter $\aleph$ is hardly ever used in mathematics for anything else rather than for [cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number). In Approach0 things like $T_1$, $U_1$, $x_1$ are matches too. Is there some way around this? (If this will need longer explanation, feel free to [respond in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2016/9/17).)

Comment: In approach0, if there is a post that has \aleph_1, then search engine will prioritize it in search results (higher rank), if you do not see relevant results, most likely the index does not contain \aleph_1. I still think returning things like x_1 (with lower.rank) is helpful in case some symbols are interchangeably used.

Comment: For your third point, $\vee$ does yield some relevant results (among top 4 as you already notice), they are symbolic equivalence matches. However, $\vee$ is defined as operator (see https://github.com/approach0/search-engine/blob/master/tex-parser/lexer.template.l#L778), that means using it without forming a valid math expression may give you unexpected results. Differentiate operator and operand in this search engine has some benefits, it is hard to explain here, mostly due to efficiency consideration and the methodology approach0 is using to search math.

Comment: For your fourth point, I have not investigated thoroughly. But this post (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934367/sum-of-the-series-sum-1-infty-fracn2n) is very recent and I am sure it is not indexed (I have not renewed our index for weeks). Also, by searching `\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{4^n}`, you will get many relevant results, although I cannot find this one (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50919/) too, but I believe the crawler missed that one, I see no reason that such a simple expression cannot be handled correctly by approach0.

Comment: Does using $\oint\frac{1}{1-z^2}dz$ help you find more relevant results? Sometimes you have to change the form of expression because currently Approach0 has no knowledge on that $\oint\frac{1}{1-z^2}dz = \oint\frac{dz}{1-z^2}$. These math convention stuffs has not been programmed into it, but definitely will improve this in future version.

Comment: As for `\oint` and `\int`, current parser makes little difference on that (see https://github.com/approach0/search-engine/blob/2fd53e5b228e1e72e445f199c4f13c404930a936/tex-parser/lexer.template.l#L662), I can change this behavior easily (need to re-index the entire MSE though), but next time you will not get any `\int` if you search `\oint`. We can discuss whether to change this in chat room.

Comment: Hmm, I did not get any `\oint` result neither, is there any `\oint\frac{1}{1-z^2}dz` really occurs in old MSE posts? (I also assume it occurs)
If there really is a posts containing `\oint\frac{1}{1-z^2}dz`, please let me know, I will investigate it.

Comment: @WeiZhong Indeed, I tested it with the other form but again no correct results were found, most probably since as you state Approach0 does not make any difference between `\int` and `\oint`. I'm pretty sure there are, but for some reason google is not able to find anything relevant, fortunately I still remember a [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1947758) from the past week that contains it.

Comment: @Workaholic Since I just moved to another city, and has not quite settled down yet, I have not updated approach0 index for at least four weeks. If it is from past week, I think it is still not indexed. But I will try to grab this post into index when I have time, just wanna test whether or not approach0 can find it. I will get back to you when I finish this experiment.

Comment: @Workaholic No luck in finding a related post. But I did a integrated test locally (see [this chat room messages](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46148/in-the-search-of-a-question)), everything works as expected.

Comment: @Workaholic I should be more specific on what message I refer to in chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32711253#32711253

Comment: @RossMillikan I have tried whether I can find the question about the series you mentioned using Google and using Approach0. You can see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46148/2016/10/6) to which extent this was successful.

Answer (score 28):

I appreciate your work and am looking forward to using it; it seems that I am not alone in this, given that your post currently has 12 - 1 votes. There is one problem though: starting by the end of August, you have posted on MSE a number of answers that only advertise your search engine and point to duplicates found with the said engine (half of those duplicates are only *superficially* duplicates). These answers of yours are not really answers, some of them got deleted, others got downvoted (by me, among others - please don't take it personally). I would appreciate your programming work even more if you stopped marketing your (otherwise nice and valuable) work. I would really be happy if you also deleted those answers.

Notice, though, that you are facing tough competition: while the internal MSE search engine is very poor (which is strange, because the engine that finds similar questions when I start typing the title of a new question, and the one that finds similar posts to be displayed to the right of a page, are very good), Google does a good job at finding not just what you *type*, but also what you *mean* (the two not always coinciding). Good luck competing with this!

Comment: I understand your point, but to clarify, my project is open source, marketing is not my interests. And it is a personal project, I have no intention to competing with any one let along Google. Those answers I posted on MSE are really just some cases when I am testing its usefulness by picking random recent MSE posts, and get excited when some previous posts **seems** relevant *to me*. Then I answered it with the mention of my project, hoping that helps and also MSE users get to know it.

Comment: @WeiZhong: Of course, when I say "marketing" I don't suggest that you are doinf it for money. Marketing can done for open source projects too. Those answers that you have written could have very well been comments.

Comment: There is an user who posts a question gets what they want and send thankful message to me. However, I am not good at judging relevance given my math level, I really agree that I may be wrong on finding similar posts. Thus I agree you on this point and going to delete some, however, some answer like  [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920037) is considered irrelevant but I have no idea why, if anyone can leave a comment under down-voted answer, just explain to me why it is a bad answer, I will learn from it and avoid similar wrong answer next time.

Comment: And thank you for that suggestion, next time if I find relevant previous post, I would rather post in comments instead of as an answer.

Comment: On 1920037, the thing to do is to vote to close as a duplicate [I just added the 5th vote to close]. Your "answer" was not an answer.

Comment: How can I normal user report a duplicate? Is it only moderators who can mark a duplicate? On [1920037](http://approach0.xyz/1920037-screenshot.png), I think this gets a little unfair that the question is marked duplicate but the person who first finds it duplicate get down voted (I am sorry, I am a new user, but could anyone tell me the correct way to report a duplicate).

Comment: @WeiZhong Re: *How can I normal user report a duplicate?* You would probably have a more reasonable chance of getting an answer if you asked it as a question rather here in comment (where not many people notice it.) I will add a link to [faq on duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). Since you are [below 3k](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) the only option for you is to [flag as a duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: @WeiZhong However, if you are not entirely sure whether a question is duplicate, perhaps reasonable thing would be to ask, for example [in this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2165/c-r-u-d-e).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you Martin, now I know how to do that! Thank you for helping me again.