# Searching for old posts from words remembered

Tags: discussion, search

I tried to search a recent topic using " hyperbolic William David crochet geometry " but had no luck.

How do advanced search options show up? Is there a more effective search method?

Thanks for search help.

EDIT1:

Apologies, my bad . Found it on YouTube:

[Hyperbolic William and David](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P37TKPGiEII)

Comment: Depending on what you mean by *recent*, it might be also reasonable to check recent posts in the some relevant tag, such as ([tag:hyperbolic-geometry]). If there is some probability that the question has been deleted, you might check [deleted questions in that tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/845253/deleted-questions-between-two-dates-in-a-specific-tag?TagName=hyperbolic-geometry&Date1=2019-01-01&Date2=2020-01-01).

Comment: BTW the title and the body seem a bit contradictory. In the title you say that you search for an *old* post, but in the question you say that you're searching for a *recent* topic.

Comment: Is it possible that you are searching for this answer:[Approximate embeddings of the hyperbolic plane in $\Bbb R^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3316729#3318413)? It mentions (William) Thurston and (David) Henderson - although only surnames are mentioned in the post, so it would not show in the query using the keywords you mentioned.

Comment: Even though it would not actually help here, I will still point out some general advice on searching here on meta: [How to search on this site?](/q/29265)

Comment: Yes sir, very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just using the built-in search engine?  I just tried it with your search string, without double quotes, with no results being found at all.  As I've seen stated several times in meta, this search engine doesn't always work well.

You should consider trying https://approach0.xyz/search/ . As [Martin Sleziak](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8297/martin-sleziak)'s comment states, it's optimized for searching formulas, but you may find it also useful for other types of searches, even if just as a secondary check. I just tried using Approach0, with it coming up with $40$ pages of results using your search text, both with & without using double quotes. I'm not familiar with Approach0, but you may wish to check its user guide to see how you can best use it. Note doing a search of "approach0" (without double-quotes) using the built-in search on meta returned $21$ results, such as [Announcing a third-party search engine for Math StackExchange.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/announcing-a-third-party-search-engine-for-math-stackexchange), from about $3$ years ago, that introduces this new option & gives some basic details about it.

Another option to consider is to use Google, but restrict it's searches to the Math SE site (and, as Martin Sleziak's comment states, you can also restrict the results to within a specific time period). You can do this by prepending your search phrase with "site:" and the site's URL, e.g., as follows:

> site:https://math.stackexchange.com hyperbolic William David crochet geometry

However, when I tried this, I got back no results. However, if you remove some search terms (e.g., the last $2$), you will likely got some results (e.g., $22$ in my test without the last $2$ terms). Also, it's handy to keep this in mind when you're doing other such searches since Google's search algorithm works differently than either the built-in search or Approach0, so I suspect it can sometimes find posts better than either of the $2$ other options.

In addition, Google can search the meta site. It also supports sub-levels so, for example, you can search only the questions (by using "site:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions"), answers (by using "site:https://math.stackexchange.com/a"), only the users (by using "site:https://math.stackexchange.com/users", with a search for my surname finding $4$ most relevant results), etc.

Comment: If the OP know that post was made relatively recently, in the built-in search engine they can try to sort the result by activity (or by newest). Google also has an option to shown only results from some specific time period.

Comment: I will also add that Approach0 is, as far as I can tell, mostly optimized for search of *formulas*.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the info. As I stated, I don't know much about Approach0, having only used it several times, so I wasn't aware it was mostly optimized for *formulas*. However, I did read that it often does a quite good job with searching with MathJax (which of course most math formulas use) in the search text.

Comment: My sincere apologies. The entry I sought was actually found  in YouTube. My bad. Having said that, I  often got frustrated searching for an old topic even when correctly entered with descriptions into MSE site search box.However response  here has been quite  helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The original book on this won the Diagram Prize for the oddest book title in 2009. I bought a copy for my sister's best friend, who was enthusiastic about crocheting. I understand Thurston was a big part of encouraging Taimina to publish as a book.

[Youtube Ted Talk by the author](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-AHvZqbMT4)

[Later book several authors](https://bookstore.ams.org/#search?crochet?page=0)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookseller/Diagram_Prize_for_Oddest_Title_of_the_Year

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the references @ Will Jagy. It is sad there is no parametric definition of corals hyperbolic geometry.. I had written to Daina Taimina in the matter I still believe 3-space parametrization is possible for a three folium (deep monkey saddle), four folium (deep Pringles chip) and so on.

Comment: @ Will Jagy Has parametrization become recently available?